# slow performance of query and scanning many rows

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

The below query is taking 6.18 min to execute for one row and the cardinality value for the exception_type = 1 is 3, I don't know how to improve the performance.

Query;

```
select count(1) as rage_tap
 
                           from summary_funnel_1066 s
                   join user_tasks_metadata utm on utm.asi = s.asi
                   join user_tasks ut on ut.id = utm.user_task_id
                   where s.seq_no = 1
                       and s.created_at between '2022-09-27 00:00:00' and '2022-10-27 00:00:00'
                       and ut.exception_type = 1
```

explain plan;

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ut
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 129554700
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: utm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: usertask_fk_idx,asi_idx,id_asi,asi
          key: usertask_fk_idx
      key_len: 8
          ref: ue_stage.ut.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,unique_asi_seq_no,seq_no_date,created_at,idx_combo
          key: unique_asi_seq_no
      key_len: 12
          ref: ue_stage.utm.asi,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

table structure;

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `summary_funnel_1066` (
  `funnel_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` int NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` int NOT NULL,
  `property_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `capture_time_relative` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_crash` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_anr` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_ragetap` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_task_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `ue_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asi`,`seq_no`,`created_at`,`app_version_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_asi_seq_no` (`asi`,`seq_no`),
  KEY `seq_no_date` (`seq_no`,`created_at`),
  KEY `last_ids` (`last_screen_id`,`last_event_id`),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`seq_no`,`property_id`,`property_name`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: user_tasks_metadata
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_tasks_metadata` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_task_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `device_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `custom_user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session_id` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_level` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `os_version` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `connection_speed` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_operator` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `config_response` tinyint DEFAULT '1',
  `total_internal_memory` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_internal_memory` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_ram` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_ram` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framework` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ue_sdk_version` mediumint DEFAULT NULL,
  `crash_type` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `associated_custom_user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_usr_interaction` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_launch_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `app_launch_time` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_metadata_filter_idx` (`custom_user_id`,`device_id`),
  KEY `usertask_fk_idx` (`user_task_id`),
  KEY `idx_app_version` (`app_version_id`),
  KEY `asi_idx` (`asi`),
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `user_profile_id` (`user_profile_id`),
  KEY `id_asi` (`user_task_id`,`asi`),
  KEY `asi` (`asi`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2252872743 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


      Table: user_tasks
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_tasks` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `app_version` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `exception_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `error_count` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `crash_type` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crash_log` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_signal_level` int DEFAULT '0',
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_important` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_video_available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_video_played` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ex` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ragetap` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s3_video_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_format` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `ue_release_version` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys_creation_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_filter_idx_2` (`app_id`,`platform`,`created_at`,`exception_type`,`app_version`),
  KEY `batch_created_idx` (`app_id`,`platform`,`batch_created_at`),
  KEY `app_id_created_at` (`app_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `id_app_id` (`app_id`,`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1636224717 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

is there any way possible to improve the performance of the query?

fdsfdfjdnfkjdkjfnkjdnjkfndkjnfjkndjkfnkjdnsfkjndsjknf

Comment: I don't know what your other queries are like, but switching `seq_no` and `created_at` columns in `s` table's primary key would enable the query to use the PK for the join and the range scanning. Not sure that creating such an index would be useful as secondary indexes contain the PK implicitly, which could ruin its usability. Indexing `exception_type` column for `ut` table can help as well - again innodb attached the pk to the secondary indexes, so I don't think you need to mention the `id` field there.

Comment: but for ut the exception_type cardinality low right what if MySQL thinks it's better to go full table scan while picking up the low cardinality?

Comment: and can i post my sample output data

Comment: If mysql thinks it is better to go for a full table scan than to use any index, then it will go for a full table scan. You can try to force its hand with use index / force index modifiers in the query and see who is right.

Comment: Didn't you post this on another forum?

Answer (score 0):

Indexes:

```
utm:  INDEX(asi,  user_task_id)
s:  INDEX(seq_no, created_at, asi)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer let me check the above index.