# how to rewrite a join query with CTE?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, common-table-expression

here I have tried to rewrite the query with cte cuz of good readability but when I try to rewrite the data is mismatched how to solve the problem for this?

Query;

```
select count(1) as rage_tap
from ue_summary.summary_funnel_1066 s
join user_tasks_metadata utm on utm.asi = s.asi
join user_tasks ut on ut.id = utm.user_task_id
where s.seq_no = 1
   and s.created_at between '2022-09-27 00:00:00' and '2022-10-27 00:00:00'
   and ut.is_ragetap = 1


Explain plan ;

*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: ut
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,idx_ir
          key: idx_ir
      key_len: 1
          ref: const
         rows: 8413412
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: utm
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: id_asi,asi
          key: id_asi
      key_len: 8
          ref: ue_stage.ut.id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: s
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,unique_asi_seq_no,seq_no_date,created_at,idx_combo,idx_seq_created_asi
          key: unique_asi_seq_no
      key_len: 12
          ref: ue_stage.utm.asi,const
         rows: 1
     filtered: 50.00
        Extra: Using where; Using index
```

Table structure;

```
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `summary_funnel_1066` (
  `funnel_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` int NOT NULL,
  `seq_no` int NOT NULL,
  `property_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `property_type` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `capture_time_relative` decimal(15,4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_event_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_message_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_tag_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_crash` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_anr` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_ragetap` tinyint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_error_type` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_screen_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `user_task_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `ue_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`asi`,`seq_no`,`created_at`,`app_version_id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `unique_asi_seq_no` (`asi`,`seq_no`),
  KEY `seq_no_date` (`seq_no`,`created_at`),
  KEY `last_ids` (`last_screen_id`,`last_event_id`),
  KEY `idx_seq_created_asi`(seq_no,created_at,asi),
  KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),
  KEY `idx_combo` (`seq_no`,`property_id`,`property_name`,`created_at`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: user_tasks_metadata
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_tasks_metadata` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_task_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `device_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `custom_user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `asi` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session_id` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `model` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `api_level` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_version_id` bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `os_version` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `location` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `connection_speed` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_operator` varchar(100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb3 COLLATE utf8_general_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `config_response` tinyint DEFAULT '1',
  `total_internal_memory` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_internal_memory` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total_ram` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `available_ram` double(12,5) DEFAULT NULL,
  `framework` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `ue_sdk_version` mediumint DEFAULT NULL,
  `crash_type` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `user_profile_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `associated_custom_user_id` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `first_usr_interaction` bigint DEFAULT NULL,
  `app_launch_type` varchar(45) DEFAULT '',
  `app_launch_time` bigint DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_metadata_filter_idx` (`custom_user_id`,`device_id`),
  KEY `usertask_fk_idx` (`user_task_id`),
  KEY `idx_app_version` (`app_version_id`),
  KEY `asi_idx` (`asi`),
  KEY `device_id` (`device_id`),
  KEY `user_profile_id` (`user_profile_id`),
  KEY `id_asi` (`user_task_id`,`asi`),
  KEY `asi` (`asi`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=2252872743 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


       Table: user_tasks
Create Table: CREATE TABLE `user_tasks` (
  `id` bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `app_id` bigint NOT NULL,
  `status` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `app_version` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `platform` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `exception_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `error_count` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `crash_type` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `crash_log` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `avg_signal_level` int DEFAULT '0',
  `is_read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_important` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_video_available` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_video_played` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ex` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_ragetap` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `session_start_time` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `network_type` tinyint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `s3_video_url` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image_format` tinyint DEFAULT '0',
  `ue_release_version` smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `batch_created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `sys_creation_date` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `session_filter_idx_2` (`app_id`,`platform`,`created_at`,`exception_type`,`app_version`),
  KEY `batch_created_idx` (`app_id`,`platform`,`batch_created_at`),
  KEY `app_id_created_at` (`app_id`,`created_at`),
  KEY `id_app_id` (`app_id`),
  KEY `idx_ir` (`is_ragetap`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1648177712 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

rewritten query;

```
with cte1 as (
    select asi,count(1) as rage_tap
    from ue_summary.summary_funnel_1066 
    where s.seq_no = 1
        and s.created_at between '2022-09-27 00:00:00' and '2022-10-27 00:00:00'
),
 cte2 as (
    select id, count(*) 'rage_tap1' 
    from  user_tasks ut where is_ragetap = 1 
) 

select cte1.*,cte2.* from cte1
inner join user_tasks_metadata utm on utm.asi = cte1.asi
inner join cte2 on b.id = utm.user_task_id
```

I need like below output;

```
+----------+
| rage_tap |
+----------+
|  1812564 |
+----------+
```

It takes time to search so I choose cte, I have tried with subquery but it does not work and it takes around 30 sec - 1.14 min.

as per this, I have indexed the column but also takes time : [slow performance of query and scanning many rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74232835/slow-performance-of-query-and-scanning-many-rows/74241052#74241052)

is there any other way to optimize it?

Comment: Rewriting shown query for CTE using makes no sense. To improve it you must create suitable indices.

Comment: The two queries aren't equivalent. In the first query you're counting all the rows in the cross product, in the second version you're counting each CTE separately.

Comment: yeah ..no idea, that's why I'm here for your help :)

Comment: What is the problem you're trying to fix?

Comment: A CTE generally only provides a benefit if you reference it multiple times in the query. It saves you from having to write the subquery twice.

Comment: like trying to optimize the performance

Comment: Use `EXPLAIN` to see the execution plan of each query, to see if it's using the indexes.

Comment: the original query takes around 30 seconds to 1.14 min after indexed.. but I want a better performance

Comment: please check i have posted the explain plan

Comment: The EXPLAIN shows all three tables are using indexes well. But the first table is examining over 8 million rows, which is probably the greatest factor in the performance problem. Using a CTE is not expected to improve that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query with two CTEs. The aggregation takes place after the tables after the joins, just as in the original query.

```
with s as 
(
  select *
  from ue_summary.summary_funnel_1066
  where seq_no = 1
  and created_at >= date '2022-09-27'
  and created_at <  date '2022-10-27'
)
, ut as
(
  select * 
  from user_tasks 
  where is_ragetap = 1
) 
select count(*) as rage_tap
from s
join user_tasks_metadata utm on utm.asi = s.asi
join ut on ut.id = utm.user_task_id;
```

As created_at is a `datetime`, you should not use `BETWEEN`, but `>=` and `<`. Please check if the date range that I put in my query matches your requirements. It excludes `2022-10-27`. If you want to include it, change this to `and created_at < date '2022-10-28'`.

Comment: sure ...thanks for the valuable answer let me check. :)

Comment: Nice ... the answer you suggested gives the exact data but the performance is slightly improved, but not that much, I think I have bad luck :/ . 

1 row in set (19.53 sec) << execution time.

Comment: CTEs don't improve the performance at all. They just help give more structure to the query here to make it more readable. Whatever improvement in speed you see, it is not due to moving the query parts into CTEs. A query (as long as it is properly written) is not the place where you look for performance gains in the first place. Instead check whether there are indexes in place that help the query. Is there an index on `summary_funnel_1066(seq_no, created_at)` or `summary_funnel_1066(created_at, seq_no)` or even the asi column at the end like in `summary_funnel_1066(created_at, seq_no, asi)`?...

Comment: Is there an index on `user_tasks(is_ragetap)` or even `user_tasks(is_ragetap, id)`? Is there an index on `user_tasks_metadata(asi, user_task_id)`? You can provide even two indexes, like the last mentioned plus `user_tasks_metadata(user_task_id, asi)`  and check which is used. Then you can still drop the other one.

Comment: Thank you for the idea let me try the index you suggested , for now, thanks for the cte answer.:)

Answer (score 1):

```
select id, count(*) 'rage_tap1' 
from  user_tasks ut where is_ragetap = 1
```

does not make sense.  There is an aggregate (`COUNT(*)`) but no `GROUP BY`.  Were you showing to get one row?  If so, which row?  `GROUP BY id` does not make since `id` is Unique.

`DOUBLE(m,n)` is worse than simply `DOUBLE`.  In fact, `(m,n)` is going away in 8.0 for `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE`.

When you have `INDEX(a,b)`, you don't need `INDEX(a)`.

`count(1) as rage_tap` is done after the JOINs, so it may have an inflated value.  Did you do a sanity check?

`utm` has two indexes on `asi`.  Toss both and add `INDEX(asi,  user_task_id)`

As for turning the Joins into Ctes, go back to when you envisioned the query.  You probably said "I need this stuff from this table", then "that stuff from that table", and finally "put things together this way".  If you can go back to that thought process, you have the CTEs.  (I don't have any idea what the data means or what the goal is, so I cannot reproduce that thought process.)